# Mixed Element Small Number - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I am creating a function that returns the smallest number within the given array. If the array contains no numbers, it should return 0.

Here's my function:

```
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr){
      if(arr.length === 0 && typeof arr === 'string'){
        return 0;
      } else{
         return Math.min.apply(null, arr); //min=1
      }
    }
    var output = findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements([4, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus']);
    console.log(output); // --> 4
```

Right now my answer return NAN instead of 4. Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`typeof arr === "string"` will always be `false` if you are passing an array (wether or not the array contain strings is irrelevant for that test).

What you should do is first, filter the numbers out of the array using `filter`, then call `Math.min` on the filtered array:

```js
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {
    var onlyNumbers = arr.filter(e => typeof e === "number"); // filter out only items that are numbers
    if(onlyNumbers.length === 0) return 0;                    // if there is no numbers, return 0
    return Math.min.apply(null, onlyNumbers);                 // otherwise return the min of them
}

var output = findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements([4, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus']);
console.log(output); // --> 4
```

Comment: I like your solution, but this won't return 0 if there are no items in the array right?

Answer (score 1):

Your current function may produce `NaN` when you try to apply `Math.min` to an input array which contains both `string` and `number` values. `Math.min` can only handle numeric inputs, so the presence of a `string` may cause it to return the `NaN` error value.

There is a simple solution: filter out all of the non-`number` values from the array. We can check the length of the filtered array to see if there were any non-numeric values and, if so, apply `Math.min` without worry.

```js
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {
  var filtered = arr.filter(function(el) {
    return typeof el == 'number';
  });
  if (filtered.length > 0) {
    return Math.min.apply(Math, filtered);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

[
  [4, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus'], // 4
  [],                           // 0
  ['a', 3, 2],                  // 2
  ['h', 'i'],                   // 0
  ['-3', 3],                    // 3
].forEach(function(input) {
  console.log(input, findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(input));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Math.min.apply(null, arr)`, you are getting `NaN` because there are strings in the array.

Your `typeof arr === 'string'` does not loop through your array to exclude string value within the array.

What you need to do to achieve your goal is to probably just do a `for` loop or `forEach` loop:

```
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr){
    var min = Infinity;

    // if argument is not array or array has no value
    if (arr.constructor !== Array || arr.length === 0){
        min = 0;
        return min;
    }

    /* for loop */
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
        if (arr[i] === 0 || typeof arr[i] !== 'number') continue;
        min = Math.min(min, arr[i]);
    }

    /* forEach loop */
    arr.forEach(function(value, index){
        if (value === 0 || typeof value !== 'number') return;
        min = Math.min(min, value);
    });

    return min;
}

var output = findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements([4, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus']);
console.log(output); // --> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should filter your array before giving it to Math.min

Try the following

```
function isNumber (obj) {
    return obj!== undefined && typeof(obj) === 'number' && !isNaN(obj); 
}

function smallestInMixedArray (arr) {
   if (arr.length === 0 || !arr.filter) {
        return 0; 
   } else { 
        arr = arr.filter(isNumber)
        return Math.min.apply(null, arr); //min=1 
   } 
}

var output = smallestInMixedArray([4, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus']);
console.log(output); // --> 4
```